# Taking limits of infimums. (or supremum)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple analysis step in a paper : https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoap/1216677126
$\textbf{Page 1405 eq (3.11)}$. A limit of an infimum is taken (note in what follows it is taken that $\inf \emptyset=-\infty$).
What is the rigorous argument to justify 
$$ \lim_{R\to \infty }\inf_{\{z\in \mathbb{R}^d:|z|\geq R\}}\inf_{\{f\in C(0,t) : f(t)=z \}}\int_0^t |f(s)|^2ds= -\infty ?$$